# change page when select option changes

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

When I change the option, the page doesn't change.
I want to change the page to '(value).html'.

```js
function countryHandler() {
  var x = document.getElementsByID("country").value;
  window.location.href = "";
}
```

```html
<select id="country" onclick="countryHandler();">
  <option value="">Country...</option>
  <option value="KR">Korea</option>
  <option value="US">United States of America</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <select id="country" onchange="countryHandler(this.value)">
    <option value="">Country...</option>
    <option value="KR">Korea</option>
    <option value="US">United States of America</option>
</select>
<script>
    function countryHandler(value) {
        window.location.assign(`${value}.html`);
    }
</script>
```

You have to listen on change in select section.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`window.location('http://example.com');`
or
`window.location.assign('http://example.com');`

Answer (score 0):

The onchange attribute fires the moment when the value of the element is changed.

```js
function urlHandler(value) {                               
    window.location.assign(`${value}`);
}
```

```html
<select id="url" onchange="urlHandler(this.value)">
    <option disabled selected value>Select Option</option>
    <option value="https://techne.africa">TechNe Africa</option>
    <option value="https://google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="https://facebook.com">Facebook</option>
    <option value="https://twitter.com">Twitter</option>
    <option value="https://instagram.com">Instagram</option>
    <option value="https://youtube.com">YouTube</option>
    <option value="https://linkedin.com">LinkedIn</option>
</select>
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.